# jQuery Validate plugin - onLoad values

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a set of `input` fields and a set of `input[type=checkbox]` fields. I have successfully added the jQuery validate for the form which encompasses those fields.

The problem comes in when a few values are already populated (on load). Validate fails to see the values on load and throws back an error when trying to submit the form with those onload values present.

Comment: could you show us the jQuery code you're using so far?

Comment: it's extremely long and won't be able to upload it. it's just that, in certain cases, i have to pre-populate content into the form fields on load. in these cases, the jquery validation plugin figures that those fields are empty.

Comment: We don't need all the code, just an example of how you pre-populate and call validate. Sounds like they are being called in the wrong order.

Comment: i have the validation call as the last thing within the onload function. plus, the values are being populated server-side.

Comment: Give us an example of these pre-populated checkboxes that don't validate correctly.  Just the checkbox HTML (as outputted to the browser) and how you call validate should be enough.